# ionic: multiple loading background for spinner

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have two spinners in different page when loading

First spinner(abc.js):

```
  $ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888,
   template: '<ion-spinner icon="android" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Loading',

});
```

Second spinner(cde.js):

```
 $ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: true, duration: 1888,
   template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner> <br/>Loading',

});
```

The css for the first spinner (abc.css) is

```
.loading{
  background-color:lightsteelblue!important;
}
```

and the second spinner (cde.css) with background color:

```
.loading{
  background-color:red!important;
}
```

However, the second background always overwrite the first spinner.
How to make both spinner has its own background color separately?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index to the spinners. Then on the 'top' spinner, give it a background-color transparent. And then change the 'top' spinners stroke property.

```
loading-md .spinner-crescent circle {
    stroke: red;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more. The code is in js or css? Please give more details

Comment: Apologies, i misread your code. You are giving both the same class ".loading". And in CSS specificity the last one declared will be displayed.

Comment: Yes. I am thinking how to differentiate both

Comment: So instead of 'class="spinner-balanced" ', replace or include 'id="spinner1" ' and in the CSS create #spinner1{ background-color:lightsteelblue }

and then do the same for spinner2